# IIS to WCF connection will not callback to IIS

Tags: c#, wcf

I have an IIS server that needs to connect via netTcpBinding to a remote machine running a WCF service. I can connect to the WCF service but the issue is the callback is not working. I have never used IIS to WCF so I think the issue is the configuration file but I have tried to find example code without luck for the specific configuration I need. My web.config file service piece on IIS looks like this.

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NET.TCP_EndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="0" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
        <binding name="NET.Callback_EndPoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://123.45.67.89:8228/My_Service" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NET.TCP_EndPoint" contract="MyWCFService.IWCFService" name="NET.TCP_EndPoint">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="net.tcp://123.45.67.89:8230/My_CallbackService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NET.Callback_EndPoint" contract="MyWCFService.IWCFCallback" name="NET.Callback_EndPoint">

      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

The IPs are obviously bogus. I inherited this config file so I have no history with it. A couple of things look wrong but so far I have not figured out what needs to be changed. The identity of the My_Service call is localhost which seems wrong but I can connect to the service and run ok. The Callback section has no identity but I read in some Microsoft docs that if the identity is missing it will auto fill the information. Can someone give me some clues as to what the issue is and how it should be configured? Thanks.

Comment: You said it was working before, and it stopped working? Do you own/administrate the server used for the callback?  Have you installed any patches around the time when things broke?  Do you have access to the .config file on the callback server (destination)?

Comment: Instead of `net.tcp` are you allowed to use https?

Comment: No I can't use https. My use for the server is new. The other users for the service exist on the same machine and they work fine. My issue is that I have to remotely connect to the machine and that seems to be the issue. There have been no patches installed in the past month or so and all other users have no issues. I can put the service on my machine and it runs fine - of course after changing the config to point to local host.

Comment: <!-- This endpoint is used for callbacks. -->
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8230/My_CallbackService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NET.TCP_Binding" name="NET.Callback_EndPoint" contract="MyWCFService.IWCFCallback">
        </endpoint> This is the service callback config

Comment: Three things to check. 1) check the windows firewall on the destination server to confirm port 8230 is open for TCP. 2) can you ping that IP from your client (the new server). If you try telnet to connect to port 8230 on that server, does it connect?  3) Check the config of your destination IIS. Does it allow anonymous connections or does it require some authentication?

Comment: The firewall is confirmed open. I can ping the port nd telnet to it. IIS does allow anonymous connections. The issue is at the WCF server and it says the credentials are not valid. The issue is that I cannot figure out what credentials the IIS is presenting to the WCF server. Is there some way to get an indication from the WCF server who it is rejecting?

Comment: Ok. the credentials are coming from your IIS application pool (new client machine). Two possible solutions: 1) set the application pool (client machine) to use a domain account (aka "utility" account). 2) if your WCF needs to know credentials (pass-through/double-hop) from the IIS client, things get complicated with Kerberos trusts, etc. Will the easy-way be satisfactory?